# slider is not showing in proper format

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, bootstrap-4

I am display slider using following code but it can not slide it display as one after another image of slide. I am store slider image in database. Give a suitable change in coding. I am using carousel-slider to display slider but it can not shown proper format.

```
<section id="slider"><!--slider-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div id="slider-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">

                        <li data-target="#slider-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>

                    </ol>

                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                         <?php 
                        $all_slider_info=DB::table('tbl_slider')->where('publication_status',1)->get();
                        ?>
                         @foreach($all_slider_info as $slider)
                        <div class="item active">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <h1><span>E</span>-SHOPPER</h1>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default get">Get it now</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <img src="{{$slider->slider_image}}" class="girl img-responsive" alt="" />
                                <img src="{{$slider->slider_price_image}}"  class="pricing" alt="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         @endforeach

                    </div>

                    <a href="#slider-carousel" class="left control-carousel hidden-xs" data-slide="prev">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#slider-carousel" class="right control-carousel hidden-xs" data-slide="next">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section><!--/slider-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the possible error might be use of active class. Your active class will be added to every slide of the slider. So it may be causing issue.  Also your code is missing indicators list. According to your code it will show only one indicator instead of every slide

```
<section id="slider"><!--slider-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div id="slider-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <?php 
                    $all_slider_info=DB::table('tbl_slider')->where('publication_status',1)->get();
                    $tot = count($all_slider_info);
                    ?>

                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <?php for($i=1;$<=$tot;$i++){ ?>
                        <li data-target="#slider-carousel" data-slide-to="{{$i}}" class="{{$i==1?'active':''}}"></li>
                    <?php } ?>
                </ol>

                <div class="carousel-inner">

                     @foreach($all_slider_info as $key=>$slider)
                    <div class="item {{$key==1?'active':''}}">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h1><span>E</span>-SHOPPER</h1>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default get">Get it now</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <img src="{{$slider->slider_image}}" class="girl img-responsive" alt="" />
                            <img src="{{$slider->slider_price_image}}"  class="pricing" alt="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     @endforeach

                </div>

                <a href="#slider-carousel" class="left control-carousel hidden-xs" data-slide="prev">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="#slider-carousel" class="right control-carousel hidden-xs" data-slide="next">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```